# How to set a property on one repository (of several)

Tags: svn, configuration, properties, repository

I want to set a property (needs-lock) for one SVN repo. I'm aware that setting properties can be done using the auto-properties in the config folder of Subversion. This is not what I want, because this setting is global and I'd like to set the property only for one repository. How can this be done?

Regards,

Johan-Kees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set a property globally for a repository, cause there does not exist a global configuration in that kind of way.

The config folder of Subversion is the configuration for your client and NOT for the Repository.

You can only set a property in particular svn:needs-lock for a particular file. But what you can is to write a script.

What you can do is to write a hook script for the particular repository to handle this locking not via a property.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I understand you correctly I have to two things. First set the property on all existing files with a script, and second, use a post-commit hook to set the property on newly created files. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes exactly this way. May be you can configure the SVN clients using auto-properties (as you mentioned already).